# Create object with one-to-one relationship in Spring Boot automatically using Jackson

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jackson

Given the following model:

**Node**

```
{id: long, value: long, parent: Node, child: Node}`
```

How can I implement this in Spring Boot, so that in the `POST` REST method you can post

```
POST: /node/1
{value: 120}

POST: /node/2
{value: 500, parent_id: 1}
```

and it automatically fetches the Node with id 1 and associates the relationship:

```
public class Node {
  long value;
  Node parent;
  Node child;
}
```

My controller method looks like this so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Node create(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Node node) {
    node.setId(id);
    nodesById.put(id, node);
    return node;
}
```

Is it even possible what I want to do or do I have to define a `parent_id`  property in my `Node` model and create the associating myself inside the controller method? I was looking into `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` but couldn't get it working.